# How do I remove a motorcycle clutch cable that has no adjustment nut?

Tags: motorcycle, clutch

I am trying to remove the clutch cable on an old motorcycle. This has no mid-cable adjuster/tensioner.

I've moved the nuts at the top of the lever as close to the lever as possible to make it loose, but I cannot figure out how to get the barrel out. It seems to need to come forward towards the front of the bike, then down. But, though the cable is as loose as possible, there is not enough slack to do this.

Would anyone know if there's any trick to doing this? I don't want to damage anything.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to remove the cable from the engine case first. You should be able to pivot the clutch actuator there and gain enough slack to remove the cable. Then, once the other end is off, you'll have enough room to remove the cable at the lever.

The other option is to remove the bolt holding the lever on, and slide it forward. Depending on the design, you may be able to take the lever off the bike, rotate it 180 degrees, and slide the end of the cable out.

Comment: And, I would suggest that the bolt is not original... Good advice though.